# SingletonMusicPlayer playing overitself

Tags: swift

I want a midi manager that means it can be called from anywhere...a Singleton instance...and handle music requests from different threads.

This is in the Playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import AudioToolbox
class MusicPlayerManager {
    static let sharedInstance = MusicPlayerManager()
    private init() {}

    var musicPlayer : MusicPlayer? = nil
    var sequence : MusicSequence? = nil
    var track : MusicTrack? = nil
    var time = MusicTimeStamp(1.0)
    var player: OSStatus? = nil
    var musicTrack: OSStatus? = nil

    func playNotes(notes: [UInt8]) {
        _ = NewMusicSequence(&sequence)
        player = NewMusicPlayer(&musicPlayer)
        player = MusicPlayerSetSequence(musicPlayer!, sequence)
        player = MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer!)
        musicTrack = MusicSequenceNewTrack(sequence!, &track)
        for index:Int in 0...6 {
            var note = MIDINoteMessage(channel: 0,
                                       note: notes[index],
                                       velocity: 64,
                                       releaseVelocity: 0,
                                       duration: 1.0)
            guard let track = track else {fatalError()}
            musicTrack = MusicTrackNewMIDINoteEvent(track, time, &note)
            time += 1
        }

        player = MusicPlayerSetSequence(musicPlayer!, sequence)
        player = MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer!)

    }

}

var notes: [UInt8] = [71,69,62,72,71,69,67]

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    MusicPlayerManager.sharedInstance.playNotes(notes: notes)
}


DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    MusicPlayerManager.sharedInstance.playNotes(notes: notes)
}



PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Unfortunately the music often doesn't play at all, or plays over itself from each instance.

At worst it should play the first instance of the music; why doesn't it nicely do that?

Comment: I do not see any implementation of a Singleton here....the sharedInstance will recall the contructor each time you call it in your programm....You must have a check that return the instance if it was already created. Where is your init method ?

Comment: Apple recommend this pattern for Singletonshttps://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton. Also called "THE RIGHT WAY" in  https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Comment: you right ! my apologizes for this comments. Its really not a classic way to define a singlton. So no ideas for your specific issue. Hope you'll find a solution. Good luck !

Comment: Could add some code showing how you're calling the singleton?

Comment: The code runs if you copy and paste it into Playgrounds (i..e the Singleton is called from sharedInstance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ran into a form of readers-writers problem here by attempting to simultaneously manipulate instance variables on your singleton from different threads. I don't know what your desired music player behavior is if it's being called from multiple threads at once, but for me one easy improvement would be to give your `MusicPlayerManager` singleton it's own `DispatchQueue`, where multiple overlapping requests can be handled sequentially.

You could define one like this:

```
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.stackoverflow.gamma", attributes: .concurrent)
```

And then wrap the code inside the `playNotes` function like this:

```
func playNotes(notes: [UInt8]) {
   self.concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
     ...
   }
}
```